# Spatial index creation in GeoServer when adding PostGIS store

Tags: postgis, geoserver, indexing

If we are adding a GeoServer store using the shapefile section, it is possible to check the option so GeoServer creates spatial index files, Is this feature available when we add store using postGIS option?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not, you have to create the spatial index when you import your data in PostgreSQL/PostGIS.

See: http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html